# Cannot remove the right end space of the output string

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
string = ''

keys = ['car', 'banana', 'groof', 'jump', 'king', 'alley']
temp = random.randint(2,3)

for i in range(temp):
    string = string + random.choice(keys) + ' '

string.strip()
print(string)
```

I'm just learning programming
Even if you use the strip function,
the space on the right end does not disappear.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `strip` function returns the modified `string` but it does't modify the orignal `string` it only `returns it` which need to be stored in another string

```
import random
string = ''

keys = ['car', 'banana', 'groof', 'jump', 'king', 'alley']
temp = random.randint(2,3)

for i in range(temp):
    string = string + random.choice(keys) + ' '

str=string.strip()
print(str)
```

Comment: Just a word of caution that using `str` as a variable name makes the `str` function unavailable in the current session.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a list comprehension along with string `join()` here:

```py
keys = ["car", "banana", "groof", "jump", "king", "alley"]
temp = random.randint(2,3)
x = ' '.join([random.choice(keys) for i in range(temp)])
print(x)
```